# How do I sort two Json strings with different types?

Tags: c#, json

Please tell me how to check which json was received.
The VK API server sends a normal response:

```
{
    "ts": "209",
    "updates": [{
            "event_id": "0237692ceafd3e",
            "group_id": 00000001,
            "object": {
                "client_info": {
                    "button_actions": ["text", "vkpay", "open_app", "location", "open_link", "callback", "intent_subscribe", "intent_unsubscribe"],
                    "carousel": true,
                    "inline_keyboard": true,
                    "keyboard": true,
                    "lang_id": 0
                },
                "message": {
                    "attachments": [],
                    "conversation_message_id": 106,
                    "date": 1709378417,
                    "from_id": 00000001,
                    "fwd_messages": [],
                    "id": 151,
                    "important": false,
                    "is_hidden": false,
                    "out": 0,
                    "peer_id": 00000001,
                    "random_id": 0,
                    "text": "Привет",
                    "version": 10000268
                }
            },
            "type": "message_new",
            "v": "5.199"
        }
    ]
}
```

And Json with an error:

```
{
  "failed": 1,
  "ts": 30
}
```

In this class, I have to skip the normal Json response and leave the Json with an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Brusketta.src.VKModels.Json
{
    internal class FailedJson
    {
        public int Response(string jsonString)
        {
            var response = 0;
            Filed? filed = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Filed>(jsonString);
            
            if (filed?.failed != 0)
            {
                response = filed.failed;
            }            

            return response;
        }
    }
    public class Filed
    {
        public int failed { get; set; }
        public int ts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When a Json response with an error arrives, everything works fine, but when a normal response arrives, I get an exception:
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32.
Cannot get the value of a token type string as a number.
Debugging shows an exception in the line

```
Filed? filed = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Filed>(jsonString);
```

Maybe there is an elegant solution to my problem in C#?

Thanks.

Sort the Json objects, get their length and compare them. Check for null.

Comment: Your method Response() is returning an 'int'.  When a good response is made you want to return a Filed.  Best solution is to change the return value to Filed.  Then when you fail return NULL.  So also change var response = null.

Comment: My code gets an exception in the Json library when I pass a string there.

Comment: Don't confuse the two different errors.  Your real issue is the deserialize has issues.  You need to add an exception handler around the deserialize so when you get an exception you return null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int Response(string json) => System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(json).RootElement.TryGetProperty("failed", out System.Text.Json.JsonElement eFailed) ? eFailed.GetInt32() : 0;
```

If you need to convert a JsonDocument you have determined to be the right type to an actual class, use the extension method group found here: `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check JSON input, please define shape of JSON data you care first. Let us assume you want JSON data which has a 'ts' property with number type value.

By using [this library](https://github.com/lateapexearlyspeed/Lateapexearlyspeed.JsonSchema), you can write as:

```cs
var jsonSchemaBuilder = new JsonSchemaBuilder();
jsonSchemaBuilder.IsJsonObject().HasProperty("ts", ts => ts.IsJsonNumber());
JsonValidator jsonValidator = jsonSchemaBuilder.BuildValidator();
ValidationResult validationResult = jsonValidator.Validate("your-json-input");
```

To check and filter it.

(I am author of that library.)

Comment: When you post answers with links to resources with which you have an affiliation, [you are expected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to disclose that affiliation in the post. Please [edit] your answer to include your affiliation. Otherwise your post may be deleted. Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).